# Why do I keep getting "error: expected unqualified-id before 'case'"?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I'm making a code where the users decide which shape they want to see using a switch statement.  I was doing fine with the first four cases but I ran into trouble when I got to the fifth one.  I Keep getting an error saying "error: expected unqualified-id before 'case' " whenever I try to make a fifth case and I can't figure out the issue.

What is happening with my code?

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int choice;
cout << "Please enter the shape you would like to see" << endl;
cout << "1. Rectangle" << endl;
cout << "2. Square" << endl;
cout << "3. Right Triangle" << endl;
cout << "4. Isosceles Triangle" << endl;
cout << "5. Kite" << endl;
cout << "6. Quit" << endl;
cin >> choice;

switch(choice){
    case 1 : double length,width; //rectangle
             cout << "Enter the length and width of the rectangle" << endl;
             cin >> length >> width;
             for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
             cout << "*";
             }
             cout << "\n";
             }
    break;
    case 2 : cout << "Enter the length and width of the square" << endl; 
             //square
             cin >> length >> width;
             for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
             cout << " * ";
             }
             cout << "\n";
             }
    break;
    case 3 : cout << "Enter the length of the triangle" << endl;      
             //right triangle
             cin >> length;
             for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
             for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
             cout << "*";
             }
             cout << "\n";
             }
    break;
    case 4 : int star=1;
             for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
             for(int j=4;j>=i;j--){
             cout<<" ";
             }
             for(int z=0;z<star;z++){
             cout<<"*";  
             }
             cout<<endl;   
             star=star+2;
             }
             }
             }
    case 5 : cout << "???";
```

Comment: Count your braces: `{` and `}`. Consistent and sensible code formatting helps tremendously. Yours is a royal mess - _learn from this!_

Comment: Case 4 is missing a break statement, unless you're intentionally falling through.

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces are mismatched. You have two extra `}` before `case 5`.

These braces should go after `case 5`. One for the `switch` statement, one for the `main` function.

In addition, your `#include` on the first line should not have *any* indentation.